# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to setup a simple file approval workflow in a google sheet:

- On column A I will have the link of a file
- On columns B, C, D I will have checkboxes for the team.
  When all 3 checkboxes are checked, the file from col A will be moved to a specific Google Drive folder.

I imported this script as a macro but I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')

- In the final version the folder ID is the correct one
- I have added from the services Google Drive and Google Sheets

```
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.range) {
    var checkboxB = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRowIndex(), 2).getValue();
    var checkboxC = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRowIndex(), 3).getValue();
    var checkboxD = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRowIndex(), 4).getValue();
    if (checkboxB && checkboxC && checkboxD) {
      var fileLink = e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRowIndex(), 1).getValue();
      var folderId = 'THIS_IS_THE_FOLDER_ID'; 
      var file = DriveApp.getFileByUrl(fileLink);
      file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
      DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).addFile(file);
      Logger.log('File ' + file.getName() + ' was moved to folder ' + folderId);
    }
  }
}

//onEdit trigger google sheet
function onEdit(e) {
  onChange(e);
}
```

Comment: Is this your exact code? This would happen if you called `onChange()` without `e` in the arguments. The error is saying that `e` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

From the question:

> I imported this script as a macro

The `onChange(e)` function you quote is designed to run through an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

The `onEdit(e)` function you quote is designed to run through a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

These triggers fire automatically when you manually edit the spreadsheet. In that context, the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e` is properly populated.

Neither function will work if you run them as a macro. If you run them as macro, the event parameter `e` is not populated, causing the error you mention. The same happens if run the code through the **Run** button in the script editor.

> In the final version the folder ID is the correct one

The `onEdit(e)` function, and any code you run through it, cannot access the `DriveApp` class because simple triggers cannot run methods that require authorization.

> I have added from the services Google Drive and Google Sheets

There is no need to do that, since you are not using the `Drive` or `Sheets` advanced services. You are using the `DriveApp` and `SpreadsheetApp` classes which are not the same thing as those advanced services.

What you need is an installable "on edit" trigger, like this:

```js
function onInstallableEditTrigger(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Install a trigger to run this function.');
  }
  if (!e.range
    || e.range.columnStart < 2
    || e.range.columnStart > 4) {
    return;
  }
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const checkboxes = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, 1, 3).getValues();
  if (checkboxes.some(value => value !== true)) {
    return;
  }
  const fileLink = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue();
  // ...proceed to move file
}
```

Create an [installable "on edit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to run the above function. You should delete your existing installable "on change" trigger and the `onEdit(e)` function.